# How to send a binary/wasm file from NestJs

Tags: javascript, express, binary, nestjs, webassembly

I tried to send a WebAssambly file with my NestJs backend as follows

```
@Get('wasm')
private getWasm(req: Request, res: Response) {
    fs.readFile('barfoo.wasm', 'binary', (err: any, data: Buffer) => {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/wasm');
        res.status(200).end(data);
    });
}
```

However, in the browser I see the following error

[image]

But when I serve the file as follows

```
@Get('wasm')
private getWasm(req: Request, res: Response) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../../barfoo.wasm'));
}
```

it all works fine.

So my question is, why is my first example not working?

UPDATE: I've extracted the code into a very basic express server

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    const file = (req.url.length > 1 ? req.url : 'index.html').replace(/^\//, '');
    console.log(`loading file ${file} for url ${req.url}`);
    fs.readFile(`./${file}`,(err, data) => {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': mime.lookup(file)});
        res.status(200).end(data);
    });
});
```

And here it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

The WebAssembly module sent to the browser is corrupted. Are you sure the code in the first case is correct? Try serving a simple text file first. Also, you should check the error object before sending the response.

Comment: I've updated the question with my latest findings. It seems to work in a normal basic express setup. 
I noticed that I'm not only using NestJs, but also `@overnightjs/core`. To be continued